# JavaScript loop through array of Object

Tags: javascript

I have this array of object:

```
let obj =  [ 
    { "id_feed": 114, "date_upd": 1666808102 },
    { "id_feed": 115, "date_upd": 1666808102 },
    { "id_feed": 116, "date_upd": 1666808102 },
] ;
```

I want to get all the **keys** and **value**. Note: this keys can dynamic, it could be anything.

So to get this I am trying :

```
Object.keys( obj ).forEach( ( item ) => {
    console.log( obj[item] )
})
```

But seems like doing wrong :(

**Expected Output:**

```
id_feed  = 114
date_upd = 1666808102
id_feed  = 115
date_upd = 1666808102
id_feed  = 116
date_upd = 1666808102
```

Comment: It's just `obj.forEach(...)`.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @bbbbbbbboat I have updated.

Comment: Well, in `Object.keys( obj )`, `obj` is not an object, but an array.

Comment: The definition of `obj` in the question indicates that `obj` is an `Array` (the naming seems to be counter-intuitive to the value). So, please try: ``console.log(...obj?.flatMap(ob => Object.entries(ob)?.map(([k, v]) => `${k} = ${v}`)));``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Object.keys()` can also do it

```js
let obj =  [ 
    { "id_feed1": 114, "date_upd": 1666808102 },
    { "id_feed2": 115, "date_upd": 1666808103 },
    { "id_feed3": 116, "date_upd": 1666808104 }
] 

obj.forEach(d1 => {
  Object.keys(d1).forEach(d2 => {
    console.log(d2 + ' = ' + d1[d2])
  })
})
```

Comment: @Shibbir I would advice your to accept Amila's answer,seems more elegant and answered more earlier

Comment: But both are same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
let obj =  [ 
    { "id_feed": 114, "date_upd": 1666808102 },
    { "id_feed": 115, "date_upd": 1666808102 },
    { "id_feed": 116, "date_upd": 1666808102 },
];

obj.forEach(item => {
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, "=", value)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
let obj =  [ 
    { "id_feed": 114, "date_upd": 1666808102 },
    { "id_feed": 115, "date_upd": 1666808102 },
    { "id_feed": 116, "date_upd": 1666808102 },
] ;

obj.forEach(o=>{
    console.log("id_feed="+o.id_feed);
  console.log("date_upd="+o.date_upd);
})
```